# Missing Final Row Qualifer in .csv and Bulk Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, csv, bulkinsert

I'm having some trouble dealing with a missing row qualifier at the end of a .csv file. I'm automatically downloading a Google sheets .csv which is then bulk inserted into a SQL server table. However what I've found is happening is that the final row of the file is not being inserted.

Looking at the file in Notepad ++, all of the lines except for the final one has a row qualifier of 'LF'.

The code I'm using to insert is below.

```
bulk insert CSVworkout
from 'C:\Users\Documents\Personal\531 Workouts.csv'
with (
fieldterminator = ',',
rowterminator = '0x0a',
firstrow=2)
```

Has anyone encountered anything similiar? Looking around, it seems this is a drawback of the Google Sheets .csv export, but is there a way I can either force the insert to recognise the final row, or is there a tool I can use to automatically populate a LF on the final row?

Any tips are very welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any other `rowterminator` values other than `0x0a`?  [Bulk Insert Row Terminator issues](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc0d3f79-3b1e-4613-881e-ba54289a5f02/bulk-insert-row-terminator-issues?forum=transactsql)

Comment: @dmason Hey Dmason, yes I've tried all manners of values. It seems that it is because the final row has no terminator (even though the others do), this line is not being recognised.

Comment: @Rhys has a possible solution.  Is that viable?  Should be pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a CRLF to the file? Plenty of different ways to do that, you could use this in a batch file;

```
echo. >> "C:\Users\Documents\Personal\531 Workouts.csv"
```

Comment: Hi Rhys, do you have any suggested resources for this? It sounds like a good solution but Google hasn't suggested a good starting point yet! Thanks.

Comment: This is not something you would normally do inside SQL Server, but a step that you could add in to the wider download & import process.